# strange behavior of child windows after setParent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke, setparent

I tried to embedded "Windows Journal" application in my Winform application by using following code. It works and everything looks good. However, when I start using Windows Journal application, which is already a child window of my application, I found the mouse behave inconsistent. Be more specific, for example, I tried to draw a line from (x, y) to (x+100, y), but the line show up on the window at (x-50, y-50) to (x, y-50). I have googling by using keywords “Mouse synchronize/inconsistent”, “application abnormal behavior after setparent, “Strange behavior of child-windows”, but not found any related solution yet. I also tried to clear the WS_POPUP style before setParent, but it didn't work. 
Could anyone give me some ideas? Thanks.

```
//IntPtr appWin is the MainWindowHandle of Windows Journal process 
ShowWindowAsync(appWin, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

// Put it into this form
SetParent(appWin, this.Handle);

// Remove border and whatnot
SetWindowLong(appWin, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);

// Move the window to overlay it on this window
MoveWindow(appWin, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
```

The code is resides in a Controller called JournalControl.cs and JournalControl is located in a splitContainer.Panel in the Main Form of the application. So, when a button of the main form be clicked, first, open a jnt file which the user indicates in Journal application

```
public void OpenJournal(string JNTPath)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(JNTPath))
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Windows Journal\Journal.exe";
            proc = Process.Start(JNTPath); 

            this.timCheckJournal = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            this.timCheckJournal.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timCheckJournal_Tick);          
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find  JNTPath: " + JNTPath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionPublisher.PublishEx(ex);
    }
}
```

Then in timCheckJournal_Tick(), puts the application inside the Panel

```
private void timCheckJournal_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timCheckJournal.Enabled = false;
    IntPtr appWin = GetJournalTopWindowHandle();
    if (appWin != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        ShowWindowAsync(appWin, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

        // Put it into this form
        SetParent(appWin, this.Handle);

        // Remove border and whatnot
        SetWindowLong(appWin, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);

        // Move the window to overlay it on this window
        MoveWindow(appWin, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
    }
    else
    {
        timCheckJournal.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Miranda why not implement MDI instead..? just curious

Comment: Well, I am actually doing this on a bit complex application. I was be asked to added a new function, which including wrap Journal application for that function. So I tried to investigate other exist functions, and this is the method I found.
I don't have many idea about MDI, and I am searching information about it, now.

Comment: I only mentioned that because of the key word that you mentioned about `Child window behavior set Parent` remember there is a difference between `Parent` and `Owner` just another hint :)

Comment: can you show the full code that you have this under meaning the Method that the code resides in..? thanks

Comment: @DJKRAZE MDI won't help here. Miranda is hosting the window from a different process.

Comment: The problem you describe in the text relates to drawing. But you didn't show any drawing code. How can we help if you won't show the code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to perform the translation between the two client areas...

Here's a link to read first: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/11570

How you implement it will depend a lot on where the mouse-drawing is initiating from and where it's supposed to be drawing to, but let's say your "hosting app" is the mouse listener and Journal is the thing you'd want to draw to - the sequence would probably look something like (pseudocode):

```
screenCoords = ClientToScreen(mouse coords)
journalCoords = ScreenToClient(screenCoords)
```

Then whatever you were doing to draw to Journal - `WM_MOUSE` messages, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I have investigating ScreenToClient api, however, it doesn't work, I guess I might use it in an incorrect way, I will keep searching for that.
Meantime, did you mean every time when a mouse event occurs, I need to translate it to Journal? It sounds very inconvenient.
Thanks :)